# How to send parallel request to Google Gemini?

Tags: python, google-gemini, google-generativeai

I have 107 images and I want to extract text from them, and I am using Gemini API, and this is my code till now:

```
# Gemini Model
model = genai.GenerativeModel('gemini-pro-vision', safety_settings=safety_settings)

# Code
images_to_process = [os.path.join(image_dir, image_name) for image_name in os.listdir(image_dir)] # list of 107 images 

prompt = """Carefully scan this images: if it has text, extract all the text and return the text from it. If the image does not have text return '<000>'."""

for image_path in tqdm(images_to_process):
    img = Image.open(image_path)
    output = model.generate_content([prompt, img])
    text = output.text

    print(text)
```

In this code, I am just taking one image at a time and extracting text from it using Gemini.

**Problem** -
I have 107 images and this code is taking ~10 minutes to run. I know that Gemini API can handle 60 requests per minute. How to send 60 images at the same time? How to do it in batch?

Answer (score 2):

In synchronous Python you can use something like a [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor) to make your requests in separate threads.

The Gemini Python SDK has an async API though, which can be a bit more natural:

```py
$ python -m asyncio

>>> import asyncio
>>> import google.generativeai as genai
>>> import PIL

>>> model = genai.GenerativeModel('gemini-pro-vision')
>>> imgs = ['/path/img.jpg', ...]
>>> prompt = "..."

>>> async def process_image(img: str) -> str:
...   r = await model.generate_content_async([prompt, PIL.Image.open(img)])
...   # TODO: error handling
...   return r.text

>>> jobs = asyncio.gather(*[process_image(img) for img in imgs])
>>> results = await jobs  # or run_until_complete(jobs)
>>> results
['text is here', ...]
```

This uses the implicit `asyncio` REPL event loop, in a real app you'll need to set up and use your own event loop.

See also [`TaskGroups`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#task-groups).

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Imagine I have a function called `model_inference` which returns the results in your code. If I call this function into a main function, do I need to use async/await or run_until_complete() ?

Comment: To answer my question: yes, it is necessary. To avoid using `async def` on all the functions you can use `loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()` and `loop.run_until_complete(your async func)`. Especially if your main function is synchronous.